# Chrome History - Is there a way to see the HTML of the pages visited?

Tags: google-chrome, history

Is there a way to see the HTML of the pages visited in Chrome history (not just the URL)?

Comment: You either have to open the page or use a good packet sniffer that can re-create HTML.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Perhaps telling us WHY you want this, what problem you're trying to solve, will go a long way towards making this answerable. Right now we can only guess at what youre actually trying to do and so our answers are all guesses too.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to see the state of the website when you visited it, and not just the current one. For that you could try using tools like [the wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a cache viewer.
I found [ChromeCacheView by Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html).
Unfortunately I found nothing else so this might be the only chance you have.

Maybe next time you want to download the page (File > Save page as...).